# How to make a site plan using Google Earth images in AutoCAD?

Tags: maps, autocad

What command do you use in AutoCAD to make a site plan (a map or something like that) of a certain place (like a school) from Google Earth? Someone told me that it is possible and it will even give you the estimated measurements.

I've watched some tutorials and they used scale to get the measurement accurate. The only problem I'm facing now is how to trace the buildings of that place without doing it manually? Is it possible?

Comment: I doubt the precision and resolution of google would be suficient to make any acurate plan. How about using a drone or a baloon?

Comment: It may be accurate depending on location, better get real mapping datathough

Answer (score 1):

If it is an architectural project, precision is very important.
But if it is for a graphic presentation or school project, Google maps will be enough. 
I did not test it but process is like this .

Create the location's map on "my maps" google .
From left menu export it as .kml and .kmz
There is a kml to dxf conversion utility [KML tools](http://kmltools.appspot.com/)

And Autocad accepting importing kml maps as well.
I can say it will not be a drawing that can be used in an architectural project.  For that, with precise measurement, you should refine the dimensions but still gonna be not precise as much as a technical drawing requires .

Answer (score 0):

Only as a weird idea: Take several Google earth satellite vistas around the same area. Extract the 3D height model of the area by using some photogrammetry tools like Photoscan. The idea is not mine, I have heard it or seen it but no idea, where. It was 2 to 3 years ago.

To stay in the topic: As already commented a real map - even Google's, if you're lucky - have all wanted roads and buildings with consistent uniform colors that are easy to trace.

Nobody can't copyright the positions of the buildings, but the used simplified collection of shapes as a map can be copyrighted. Remember to read the disclaimer to see, how much you can copy "as is".

Addendum:

In every town hall should be an office that has up to date street and building maps available for reasonable fee - even as free. Those maps probably are Autocad  compatible because a constant demand exists on them by buiders and those who design the future.

Comment: There is nit enough paralax in most satelite images